# How to loop through values in a dictionary to see if they ever appear as a key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary (*i.e.,* `my_dict`). Basically each `key` is a sick person and the `values` for that key are the people they have been in contact with. I need the people that occur only in the values and never in the keys. **Philip and Sarai** are the **only names** that appear as values but not keys.

This is the code I have tried so far. How can I change it to effectively loop through the values to determine if they ever appear as a key?

```
my_dict = {'Bob': ['Paul', 'Mark', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
           'Carol': ['Mark', 'Leanne'],
           'Farley': ['Paul'],
           'Leanne': ['Sarai'],
           'Larry': ['Carol', 'Mark', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
           'Mark': ['Philip', 'Zach'],
           'Paul': ['Zach'],
           'Will': ['Leanne', 'Mark'],
           'Zach': ['Philip']}

list = []
for key in my_dict:
    variable = True
    for value in my_dict.values():
        if key in value:
            variable = False
    if variable == True:
        list.append(value)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want in a fairly straight-forward, readable, and efficient manner, as shown below. I made `only_values` a `set` to prevent duplicates as you requested in a comment.

```
my_dict = {'Bob': ['Paul', 'Mark', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
           'Carol': ['Mark', 'Leanne'],
           'Farley': ['Paul'],
           'Leanne': ['Sarai'],
           'Larry': ['Carol', 'Mark', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
           'Mark': ['Philip', 'Zach'],
           'Paul': ['Zach'],
           'Will': ['Leanne', 'Mark'],
           'Zach': ['Philip']}

only_values = {person for people in my_dict.values()
                          for person in people
                              if person not in my_dict}

print(only_values)  # -> {'Philip', 'Sarai'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There already some good posts for answering this question earlier. Here I just presented more step-by-step to approach this problem:

```
patients = my_dict          #  more descriptive variable
vals =  list(patients.values())
uniq_patients = set(sum(vals, []))
print(uniq_patients)

for person in uniq_patients:
    if person not in patients: print(person)



Output:
{'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Paul', 'Philip', 'Zach', 'Sarai', 'Will', 'Mark'}
Philip
Sarai
```